# Put an image on Google map

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps

I am creating a web page which shows the Google map using JavaScript. How can I put an image on that map as a icon.  Here is what I have:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var lat=1067;
    var lon=-110;

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon), 13);
      }
    }
    function map(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        load();
    }
    function get_location() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(map);
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
<input type ="Button" size = "50" onclick = "get_location();">Search</input>
<div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you used to make the map. Also, where do you want to image/icon to be placed on the map? Anywhere, or at a specific location?

Comment: hello Bryan,

Thanks for the reply. Actually above code is just for find the location when i click on that button. I want a image will popup when it's find my location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons in Google Maps are part of the "Overlay" section in the documentation. [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Icons) is a link to the relevant portion of the documents.

In short:

```
  var image = 'beachflag.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856); //or wherever you want the marker placed
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
```

Comment: Hello Scottie, 
Thanks for the reply 

function map(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        load();
    }
This function is finding my current location. 

So please tell me wether i am right or not?

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng (lat,lon);

Comment: That should work, yup. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Hey Scottie,
I am new here in java script and as well as in google map. I put an image in the same folder where this html file resides and make some changes in code but it not works .Try this link to see that code :

http://codepad.org/nyLJxfzP

Comment: Ah, you're using Google Maps APIv2, the information I gave you was for v3. V2's been officially deprecated. If possible, you really should look into using v3 instead.

Comment: Would you please make some changes in this file for above one..It's very urgent

Answer (score 0):

I use the setIcon function from Google Maps API (v3) like:

```
// This is our marker image, sets the size and position (from the center of the map)
this.image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/gfx/map/icon_hotel.png",
    // This marker is 22 pixels wide by 28 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(22, 28),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,28
    new google.maps.Point(11, 28)
);

// This is our marker shadow. Same location as marker, but different dimensions
this.shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/gfx/map/icon_hotel_shadow.png",
    // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
    // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
    new google.maps.Size(33, 28),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(11, 28)
);
```

There's an example of this by Google at: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex.html